# Adobe Air application close when select a lot of files

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, air

In my application, when I load a lot of files (more than 100~) the application close automatically.

I'm using FileListEvent.SELECT_MULTIPLE, this application is only to get the name of files.

```
function selectFile(e: MouseEvent): void {

    file_selected.browseForOpenMultiple("Selecionar fotos:", [jpgFilter]); 
    file_selected.addEventListener(FileListEvent.SELECT_MULTIPLE, onFileSelected); 
}

function clearTextArea(e:MouseEvent):void {
    textArea.text = "";
    txt_folder.text = "";
}

function onFileSelected(e: FileListEvent): void {
    trace("test");
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < e.files.length; i++) 
    {
        //trace("NOME: " + e.files[i].name);
        obj_list.push({file_name:e.files[i].name});
    }

    fileInformation(obj_list[email_number].file_name);
}


function fileInformation($name:String):void {

    var domain_name:String = "";
    var file_name:String = $name;
    var nome:String;
    var email:String;

    if(file_name.indexOf(divisor) != -1){
        nome = file_name.slice(0, file_name.indexOf(divisor) - 1);
        email = file_name.slice(file_name.indexOf(divisor) + 2, file_name.length).toUpperCase();
    }

    if(email.indexOf("(") != -1){
        email = email.slice(0, email.indexOf("(") - 1);
    }

    trace("Nome: " + nome);
    trace("Email: " + email);

    textArea.appendText(String("\n" + email).toUpperCase());

    email_number++;
    if(email_number <= obj_list.length - 1){
        fileInformation(obj_list[email_number].file_name);
    }

}
```

There is a limitation for loading multiple files?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: It could be an operating system limit.

Comment: There is no error msgs. Only close the application. I think that is an operating system limit too. Maybe a memory error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If selecting multiple files is crashing the app, I can only think of some work-arounds...

Option 1) Why not change the logic? Try as:

- User will browse/selects one jpeg from the required folder.
- Then your app auto-scans the same folder to get all file names with text `.jpg` in each file's own specific `file.name` or `file.url` text.

Option 2) Use an external program to get file names list. If you're on Windows you could command line (*eg:* `cmd.exe` with its `dir` option). Something like...

Use `cmd.exe /K "cd /d e:\myImagesFolder\"` to run command line from `E:\` drive's `myImagesFolder`.
Then use `dir *.jpg` to get a list of all jpegs in folder.

Maybe receiving the command line output into your AIR app could be a workaround to the crash issue?

Code below is untested but you want this logic for command line output: 
(no terminal window will pop-up, it's a silent/invisible run but you can see `cmd.exe` listed in Task Manager) :

```
var file_selected :File = File.documentsDirectory;
var user_Folder_Path : String = ""; //# update with User folder path (after they selected 1 file)
var str_Temp : String = "";
var str_Files : String = "";

var processInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();

function selectFile (e :MouseEvent) :void 
{ 
    file_selected.browseForOpen("Selecionar fotos:", [jpgFilter]);  
    file_selected.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelected); 
} 

function fileSelected(event:Event):void 
{ 
    str_Temp = fileToOpen.nativePath;

    //# trim down to folder path eg: remove file name part
    user_Folder_Path = str_Temp.substring(0, str_Temp.lastIndexOf("\") );

    str_Temp = str_Files = ""; //reset both strings

    if(NativeProcess.isSupported)
    {
        processInfo.executable = new File("C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe");
        processArgs.push("dir *.jpg" + " " + user_Folder_Path );
        processInfo.arguments = processArgs;

        process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, std_onStandardOutputData);  
        process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, std_onError);

        process.start(processInfo);
        process.standardInput.writeUTFBytes(processArgs + "\n"); 
    }
}

function std_onStandardOutputData(evt:ProgressEvent):void  
{  
    var process:NativeProcess = evt.target as NativeProcess;  
    var data:String = process.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable);  
    str_Files += data; //holds file names as they come in from CMD.exe
}   

function std_onError(evt:ProgressEvent):void 
{                    
    var process:NativeProcess = evt.target as NativeProcess;  
    var data:String = process.standardError.readUTFBytes(process.standardError.bytesAvailable);  
    str_Temp += data; //holds other text data from CMD...                     
}
```